# RavenDB - How to convert a string field into int in a Lucene query?

Tags: c#, lucene, ravendb, lucene.net, ravendb-studio

I am working with a bunch of documents in `RavenDB` that have an `Age` field that has to be an `int` but unfortunately they have been stored as `string`.
I want to write a query to get all the docs with ages more than 20 here's what I do :

```
Age : [20 TO *]
```

But I am getting docs with ages of `3 to 9`  too.(strings are compared from left hand side)

The question is how can I tell `Lucene` to treat age as `int` ?

(This system is somehow a legacy system I can't change the Age type in documents)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
Age_Range: [Ix20 TO *]
```

Comment: this way I am getting no result at all?

Comment: Post this in the mailing list.